# NameError: name 'roi_gray' is not defined

Tags: opencv, python

when run it says PS C:\Users\Windows 10> python -u "d:\tugas sem 1\pak angga\deteksimasker\Pendeteksi\bismillah deteksi wajah 2.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\tugas sem 1\pak angga\deteksimasker\Pendeteksi\bismillah deteksi wajah 2.py", line 27, in 
hidung = nosecascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray, 1.18, 35)
NameError: name 'roi_gray' is not defined
[ WARN:0] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
PS C:\Users\Windows 10>
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZajc.png)

Comment: You are asking a question totally out of context of your code. Please show your code and where the error occurs.  Welcome to Stack Overflow. **Please read** the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In line 19, put inside of the if/else block.

Answer (score 0):

if the value of wajah is []
then there will not be the value of roi_gray

but line 19 is accessed every time .. that is the error